# Returning a value from a stored procedure after value has been used in an If statement

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have a simple MSSQL stored procedure that should query a table and return a value.

I have added an IF Statement after my SELECT to perform an action should a match be made. However this IF Statement is preventing the @countrycode value from being returned.

So my question is, how do I return the @countrycode value whilst still performing the IF action?

Please feel free to suggest a more elegant method.

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @countrycode VARCHAR(10)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @countrycode = countrycode FROM tblIpLocation WHERE ipnumber = @ipnumber

-- Perform action if countrycode is found
IF @countrycode is null
    PRINT 'Nothing found'
ELSE 
    -- Increment the positivequerycount column in the same row from which the countrycode was made
    UPDATE tblIpLocation 
             SET positivequerycount = positivequerycount + 1 
             WHERE ipnumber = @ipnumber

END
```

Comment: Have you tried a `BEGIN` and `END` inside the `ELSE` ?

Comment: I see no code that will return the value of the variable. To return the value, you need either `SELECT @countrycode` or to return the value as an output parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dan Guzman, you got me on the right track.

I had tried the following to return the value...

```
SELECT @countrycode
```

However, of course it needs to be...

```
SELECT @countrycode AS countrycode
```

The final solution is..

```
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @countrycode VARCHAR(10)

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT @countrycode = countrycode FROM tblIpLocation WHERE ipnumber = @ipnumber


-- Perform action if countrycode is found
IF @countrycode is null
    PRINT 'Nothing found'
ELSE

    -- Increment the positivequerycount column in the same row from which the countrycode was made
    UPDATE tblIpLocation SET positivequerycount = positivequerycount + 1 WHERE ipnumber = @ipnumber

    SELECT @countrycode AS countrycode
```

END

Thanks for your help

Comment: For future reference, post ALL of the stored procedure code and not just what you consider to be the relevant part. Editing - even simple editing - for posting often introduces additional problems, adds confusion, and hides existing problems. In addition, you probably should NOT be mixing output styles. Print generates a message which should be processed by whatever app executes the procedure - and often apps do not expect to do such things when they expect a resultset.